# How to return a value of Future when its done?

Tags: scala, playframework, scalatest

I wrote a simple method that returns List of Int based on a service call i perform in it.

my problem is that the service call im making is returning a future of some value, so I thought i can do onComplete and return what I want on complete of the future, but onComplete returns Unit...

this is how I wanted it to work:

```
  def getListOfInts(str: String): List[Int] = {
    myDaoService.findSomethingInDb(str).onComplete {
      case Success(res) =>
        res.map(line => line.amount.toInt*100).distinct.filter(num => num != 0).toList
      case Failure(exception) => logger.error(s"finding in db has failed with exeption: ", exception)
    }
  }
```

what is the right way to return the wanted value of a future when it completed?

i know usually its `map/flatmap` but this will keep it wrapped in the future and I want my method to return the actual value and not future of the value...

thanks!

Comment: scala-async might be able to help you: https://github.com/scala/async

Answer (score 2):

**`Await.result` is the way to go, but Its not recommended.**

```
import scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext.Implicits.global
import scala.concurrent.duration._
import scala.concurrent.Await

def getListOfInts(str: String): List[Int] = {
  Await.result(myDaoService.findSomethingInDb(str), 10 seconds).map(line => line.amount.toInt*100).distinct.filter(num => num != 0).toList
}
```

The above way is not recommended until and unless you want to make the thread of execution wait(block) for the result. The above code does not scale.

**Recommended way**

```
def getListOfInts(str: String): Future[List[Int]] = 
myDaoService.findSomethingInDb(str).map { res =>
  res.map(line => line.amount.toInt*100).distinct.filter(num => num != 0).toList
}
```

The recommended way is to compose the future (use map and flatmap to transform the output type of the database call into the required result) and then finally doing waiting to get the final transformed result.

Comment: You should only ever use Await.result() in test code

Comment: Exactly, you can accept this answer. You have a sync method which uses an async API, so you have to either await for the result (which is not really recommended) or you have to make your whole code async (returning Futures in turn).

Comment: @sheunis Sometimes it's our of your hands, for instance when you have two libraries, one async and the other one sync. So you have to use Await (which is ugly but at least there are versions of Await which do not busy wait and block the thread from making progress), or you have to ditch the sync (or async) library, or you have to make the sync library async (which sometimes is simply impossible).

Answer (score 0):

http://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/core/futures.html

onComplete, onSuccess and onFailure are the callbacks you are looking for